# Does Java Apache httpclient need Server certificate to call https service?

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-httpclient-4.x, tls1.2

I need to call a vendor https service from Java Spring boot application. As per Vendor, this service supports TLS 1.2 which looks like is enabled by default in Java 8. And when I asked the vendor for their server certificate, they said we don't need the certificate as they use verisign issued root certificate which is already present in the Java truststore.

But when I used Apache httpclient to call this service without setting any ssl context explicitly, I got following error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I read few answers on Stack overflow which talk about setting the ssl context to trust the external service without their certificate. But I am not sure whether this is the right way. Please note that I am running spring boot with Java 8 on a Windows 7 machine.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this issue. Although the vendor was using Verisign issued root certificate which is present in the Java default truststore, turns out our IT security team had turned on SSL inspection on all outgoing requests and instead of Verisign, we were seeing the SSL certificate issued by the security proxy when accessing the vendor service. And as that certificate wasn't in the truststore, I got SSL handshake error.

To make this work on our machines, I created a jks keystore and added the security proxy certificate to it. Of course, I don't have to do this on production environment because our servers don't (obviously) have SSL inspection.

Other easier option would have been to just ask IT team to exclude the vendor service from SSL inspection.